# WHY does the red square drop down when text is inserted?

Tags: html, css

When "WHY?" is absent in the first div, the two squares are side by side. When it is present, the red square drops down? Why is this happening? Beginner question I know.

```css
body{
 margin: 0
}

div {
 border: 10px solid;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px
}

#ed{
 border-color: red
}

#ed2{
 border-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="ed">WHY?</div>
<div id="ed2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the default [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for inline elements is `baseline`. To get them to line up as you're expecting, set it to top:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

div {
  border: 10px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#ed {
  border-color: red
}

#ed2 {
  border-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="ed">WHY?</div>
<div id="ed2"></div>
```